# Does the Oracle Pro*C 10.0 pre-compiler require floating-point host variables to be in IEEE format?

Tags: openvms

We are migrating our forecasting database from Oracle 10.2 to Oracle 12.1.  This means that we have to replace the Oracle Pro*C 9.2.0.3.0 pre-compiler with Pro*C 10.2.0.5.0.

All of our application programs are built and run under OpenVMS Alpha 8.4. We have traditionally compiled our programs with /FLOAT=G_FLOAT, the native VAX floating-point format.

- A program built with Oracle Pro*C 9.2.0.3.0 and VAX floating-point gives correct results.
- A program built with Oracle Pro*C 10.2.0.5.0 and VAX floating-point gives invalid results.  We got errors and NaNs for the same programs reading the same data.
- A program built with Oracle Pro*C 10.2.0.5.0 and IEEE floating-point gives correct data results.

From the results it appears that the Oracle Pro*C 10.2.x pre-compiler requires that host variables use the IEEE floating-point format.

What do others think? Is there any Oracle documentation on this?

Comment: Does [this](https://community.hpe.com/t5/Operating-System-OpenVMS/IA64-Oracle-10g-10-2-and-G-FLOATS/td-p/3826381#.XKVfOdh7nmE) article help?